# How to configure apache as reverse proxy for HTTPS tomcat7 backend?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, ssl, https, tomcat

I have configured my tomcat7 to use letsencrypt SSL successfully on port 8443.
Now I want to accept for 443 port only I am using apache2 in front of it.
I added virtual host and this is the content on ubuntu /etc/apache2/available-site/example.com.conf:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias *.example.com
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyRequests off

      <Proxy *>
              Order deny,allow
              Allow from all
       </Proxy>

SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLVerifyClient None
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem



ProxyPass / https://localhost:8443/
ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8443/
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
```

and this is the content of tomcat 7 server.xml related to SSL:

```
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
            port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
            connectionTimeout="20000"
            redirectPort="8443" />


<Connector
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           port="8443" maxThreads="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" keystoreType="PKCS12"
           keystoreFile="/home/ubuntu/example.jks" keystorePass="example"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

when I tried to connect to using elinks:

```
$ elinks https://localhost
```

I got this message:

```
503 proxy Error the proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
```

Also Should I configure certificate location for Apache also or just tomcat 7.
Any help!

Comment: The same comment as added to your identical question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/899764/how-to-configure-apache-as-ssl-reverse-proxy-for-tomcat7).  Your Tomcat is running HTTPS, but you Apache `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` only has `http`.  I'd delete one of the questions :-)

Comment: This is typo I fixed it.